# Filling remainder of the page with dots

Tags: fill

I try to fill the remainder of the page with dots but the `\dotfill` command isn’t enough because it only fills with dots until the end of line.

I want to let in my document two pages witch only contain dots.

So, how can I do it?

Comment: what sort of spacing do you want?  same distance between dots both horizontally and vertically, or would rows of dots spaced vertically at baseline distances apart be satisfactory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an idea:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\dotcolumnfill{%
    \par
    \null
    \vskip -\ht\strutbox
    \xleaders \hb@xt@ \hsize {%
        \strut \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss.\hss}\hfill
    }\vfill
    \vskip \ht\strutbox
    \break
}

\makeatother




\begin{document}

With some text before.
\lipsum*[1]
\dotcolumnfill

\lipsum[2]

Whole pages of dots follow.

\newpage
\dotcolumnfill
\dotcolumnfill

Some more text.

\end{document}
```

But perhaps the OP would prefer `\leaders`, instead of `\xleaders`, for the vertical glue…

Answer (score 1):

Using `tikz` with dots in the background.[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.south west)},x=1in,y=1in]
\foreach \x in {0, ..., 85}
\foreach \y in {0, ..., 110} {
    \draw[fill,LightGrey] (0.1*\x,0.1*\y) circle(0.01in); 
}
\end{tikzpicture}

This is the coolest effect ever seen. 

\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It isn’t exactly what I search, I don’t try to put dots in backgrounds but after the text.

Comment: Ok, that's not what I had understood from your original question.

Comment: In that case, Gustavo's answer gives you precisely what you want, so I suggest you accept it.