# Filling remainder of the page with dots (again)

Tags: fill

I have the same question as [Filling remainder of the page with dots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319430/filling-remainder-of-the-page-with-dots). That is, I want to fill the remainder of the page with dots. The accepted answer is almost perfect, but when I use it inside `\begin{enumeration}`, the dots are not indented properly. Is there a way to get it to work?

I found answers in other posts suggesting that `leavevmode` would help, but it doesn't appear to work wherever I add it.

Edited: here's the code that I have tried. I simply added `leavevmode` in front of `cleaders` on top of the aforementioned accepted answer.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\dotcolumnfill{%
    \par
    \null
    \vskip -\ht\strutbox
    \xleaders \hb@xt@ \hsize {%
        \strut \leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss.\hss}\hfill
    }\vfill
    \vskip \ht\strutbox
    \break
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \lipsum*[1]
  \dotcolumnfill
  \item \lipsum*[2]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: I added the code that I tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `linegoal` package to find out how wide the dot column should be. This requires 3 compilations to settle on the correct value.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\dotcolumnfill{%
    \par\noindent\mbox{}\@tempdima=\dimexpr\linewidth-\linegoal
    \null
    \vskip -\ht\strutbox
    \xleaders \hb@xt@ \hsize {%     
        \hspace{\@tempdima}\strut \leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss.\hss}\hfill
    }\vfill
    \vskip \ht\strutbox
    \break
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \lipsum*[1]
  \dotcolumnfill
  \item \lipsum*[2]
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum*[3]
\dotcolumnfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the additional question raised in the comments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\dotcolumnfill[1][0]{%
    \par\noindent\mbox{}\@tempdima=\dimexpr\linewidth-\linegoal
    \null
    \vskip -\ht\strutbox
    \ifnum#1=0\relax
    \xleaders \hb@xt@ \hsize {%     
        \hspace{\@tempdima}\strut \leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss.\hss}\hfill
    }\vfill
    \vskip \ht\strutbox
    \break
    \else
    \@tempcnta=0\relax
    \loop
    \advance\@tempcnta by1\relax
    \hb@xt@ \hsize {%       
        \hspace{\@tempdima}\strut \leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss.\hss}\hfill
    }%
    \ifnum\@tempcnta<#1\relax
    \repeat
    \fi
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \lipsum*[1]
  \dotcolumnfill
  \item \lipsum*[2]
  \dotcolumnfill[4]
  \item \lipsum*[3]
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum*[4]
\dotcolumnfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I do not fill all remainder of the page, but, number of line, e.g, 10 lines. How can I do that?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 I added a second version for that.

Comment: Thanks. When I use `\dotcolumnfill[4]`, I only get three rows with dots. Can I got 4, and `\dotcolumnfill[n]`, I get `n` rows fill dots.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 I think you should have gotten 3 but yes, there was a mistake. Now it should work.

Comment: Thanks. Now it is correct.

Comment: please try
`\begin{document}
Row of dots of the first row  seems too near with above line.
 \dotcolumnfill[5]
\end{document}
`

Comment: @minhthien_2016 You can remove the `\vskip -\ht\strutbox` after `\else`.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below macro.

```
  \makeatletter
        \newcommand*\dotcolumnfill{%
            \par
            \null
            \vskip -\ht\strutbox
            \xleaders \hb@xt@ \hsize {%
                \strut \leavevmode \hphantom{1111l}\cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss.\hss}\hfill
            }\vfill
            \vskip \ht\strutbox
            \break
        }    
    \makeatother
```

[image]